# Do I need to start fresh? I think I messed up X-window

Tags: ssh, kodi, xorg, osmc

Long story short I can't get my pi 3 B+ to display kodi running on osmc because I jacked up the X-windows possibly? I'm wondering if there is a way for me to reinstall what is creating my GUI going out the HDMI port to my TV?

Long story:

So I picked up a raspberry pi 3 B+ and have been experimenting with OSMC and Kodi on it. I had everything running with a few repositories last night and had an ssh set up from my laptop to it but wanted to experiment with tightvnc. After getting the the server setup up on the pi I initiated a viewer and received an error that led me to a better understanding of what I *thought* I was trying to do. I thought I was trying to set up a team viewer experience where I could use and view kodi from my laptop in my home network. I realize that's not really possible now. I still wanted to get this teamviewer working so I wound up putting the following in through ssh

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all \
xserver-xorg-video-fbdev libx11-6 x11-common \
x11-utils x11-xkb-utils x11-xserver-utils xterm lightdm openbo
```

I thought that would give me what I needed and for a few brief shining moments I had success. Then I restarted my pi. Now I am getting artifacting on kodi. When  my pi boots up now it goes from the osmc logo to a login page for a brief second then rolls right into kodi. The login looks ubuntuish with a gray person icon next to user and password. Kodi is functional for a few seconds but then crashes either by freezing the image or going black. It stays functional for about 30ish seconds on TV from the attached mouse and keyboard.

Here is where I get really confused. I can still access the pi after I start my SSH session. I am able to actually access my files with winscp and even though the screen is frozen right now I am downloading video files from the pi back to my laptop right now. I can also still connect with tightvnc viewer but all i see is a grey screen and a black x cursor. When I had run the above apt-gets is where the issues started.

I'm pretty sure I'm out of my depth here and I know I could just do a fresh install on my sd card but I'd really rather fix this. I feel like maybe I have somehow installed multiple operating systems essentially maybe? Oh and there is plenty of space on the SD card. I popped it out and checked it. It's a 32 gig card with less than half used right now so memory isn't an issue. Power supply is adequate and it is cooled. The peripherals don't affect performance when in or out. Since I still have function of the Pi at the ssh terminal level I should be able to fix this right?

Is there something I can to to check repository redundancies or anything like that?